# How to skip saving form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

There's the inline in my admin form and I would like just to skip saving a line if one of it's field is empty.

I don't need to raise ValidationError and ask user input data into this field.

How can I do that? I've tried to override my form but Django tries to save the instance.

Here's my form:

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_clean(self):
        super(MyAdminForm, self).full_clean()
        if 'my_field' in self.errors:
            del self._errors['my_field']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        m = super(SuperSetAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if m.my_field is not None:
            m.save()
        return m
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data.get('my_field'):
        super(SuperSetAdminForm, self).save()
    return
```